# Find basis for $P_0^\perp \subset P_4$ and $\ker (f \mapsto f(0))$ in $P_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, bilinear-form

Let $P_n \subset \textrm{Map}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ the space of polynomial maps $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with degree $\le n$. We define $\langle f,g\rangle := \int_{-1}^1 f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$.

i) Find a basis for $P_0^\perp \subset P_4$.

ii) Find a basis of the orthogonal complement of $\ker (f \mapsto f(0))$ in $P_4$.

Comment: Since you define the inner product as you define it, shouldn't the polynomial maps be just $[-1, 1] \to \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No, $\textrm{Map}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ are all polynomials from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. I think the form is a hermitian form since that would fit in the context and we have the complex conjugate.

Comment: But what does it mean to apply $∫_{-1}^1$ on $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ map? Instead of applying it on the restriction to $\mathbb{R}$ it could mean integral over set $[-1, 1]$ which has measure zero on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think it's just the definition of the form... I don't really know, that's why I posted the question here.

Answer (score 0):

For first one, you should see, that $P_0$ is generated by $1$ and $P_4$ by $1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4$. So just apply Gramm-Schimdt ortogonalization.

For the second one, you first should identify, what the $\ker$ is.